# i need Only one check box to be checked the other not to be allowed to check

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, silverlight-5.0

I'm using RadGridview and its FooterRow contains 3 Check Boxes.Now if i want to allow only one checkbox to be checked and the other two should not be allowed to check how should I implement it? i need to implement.

Like the Radio buttons.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have any controls in a FooterRow, can you not actually use Radio Buttons rather than checkboxes?

If you have a situation where you want to have a checkbox at the foot of each column and only one of those checkboxes can be selected, you probably need to provide a little more information about the intent you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i must have to use check box only it's requirement... based on which check box is checked that column data i have to use in another scenario... for that if  any of check box checked the other two not allowed to check...

Comment: Unless someone in the know comes up with a clever way of handling it, I guess you are probably going to have to do it the long way round - when a checkbox is selected, programatically set the others to unselected. Is there a reason that it *must* be in the footer though? Would you be able to consider variants in the UI to still enable you to select the significant column for additional processing?